# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am using Typescript in my React-native project.Code working properly as per desired output.but getting typescript conflicts.

Sharing my code snippets

Importing json object from other config files.

```
import api from 'config/api.json'
```

```
  languageSet = async (value: string) => {
  setStorageItem('language', value)
  this.setState({ setLoading: true })

  const language = await getStorageItem('language');

  if (language) {
    const baseURL = api[language][environment] ? api[language][environment].api : api[language].qa.api;
  
  }
  else {
    const baseURL = api.ch[environment] ? api.ch[environment].api : api.ch.qa.api;
  }
}
```

I want to make dynamic baseURl that's why using language const to set it's value.
Following error I am facing.

[image]

Comment: can you share the structure of the API object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put type on the `getStorageItem` function

try this way

```
const language = await getStorageItem('language') as 'ch';
```

if you have some language you can do

```
const language = await getStorageItem('language') as 'ch' | 'other_language';
```